# Passing option id from select element to form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using a `select` form element to render multiple options and then show corresponding text from a database in the text area using an `onchange` event.

The value of the `select` option's are very long, so I'd like to pass the `id`, or `name` of the option, to my form target favorite.php, but I don't know how to do it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="had">
 <form name="det" action="vispage.php" method="POST">
      <label for="hadeath">Selct Title of the Hadeath</label>
      <select name="header" onchange="document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=this.value">

           <?php foreach($hadeeth as $i) {?>
        <option id="<?php echo $i['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $i['short']; ?>"><?php echo $i['name']; ?></option>

<?php } ?>
</select><br><br>

   <label for="a">tree :</label><br>
   <textarea id="txt" name="tree" rows="15" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>

   <a href="favorite.php" style=" width: 100px; padding:10px; " id="idd" class="btn" role="button">Add to Favorites </a> </form>

</div>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$title = "hadeeth";
include_once ("header.php");
include 'connect.php';


//CREATE THE QUERY

$query = "SELECT * FROM `search`";

//RUN THE QUERY
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$hadeeth = array();

// RETRIEVE VALUES FROM RESULT
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$hadeeth[$row['name']] = array(
     'id'=>$row['id'],
     'name'=>$row['name'],
     'short'=>$row['short']
     );

}

?>
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use the href in order to pass the value or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: @Terminus I can also use buttons

Comment: What about changing where the form submits to?

Comment: @Terminus how??

Comment: @layla7 Do you want to pass the ID as query String?